# Java searching file

Tags: java, file, io, save, stringbuilder

I have 2 string variables:

"**givenAccnt**" is the input string obtained from user

"**accntToken**" is a substring (first string) of a line of text

If givenAccnt **equals** accntToken, I want to return *the line* of text matched by accntToken.

Furthermore, there may be cases where there are more than 1 match. I want to save all matches to a variable and then return those matches (lines) at once.

The code below is only returning match on the last line. (If match is in other lines it misses it)

I can't seem to figure why is it behaving that way.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
givenAccnt = searchTextField.getText();//else, user is using search field to get given account
try
   {
      scanner = new Scanner(file);        //initialize scanner on file
      while(scanner.hasNextLine())        //while lines are being scanned
      {   
         getLine = scanner.nextLine();          //gets a line
         int i = getLine.indexOf(' ');          //get first string-aka-accnToken
         accntToken = getLine.substring(0, i);    
       }
       if(givenAccnt.equals(accntToken))   //if match   
       {
          collectedLines = new StringBuilder().append(getLine).toString();
          psswrdLabels = new JLabel(collectedLines, JLabel.LEFT);
          psswrdLabels.setAlignmentX(0);
          psswrdLabels.setAlignmentY(0);
          fndPwrdsCNTR += 1;     //counter for number of passwords found 
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, psswrdLabels ,+fndPwrdsCNTR+" PASSWORD(S) FOUND!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);    //shows window with matched passwords (as JLabels)
                            searchTextField.setText("");    //clears search field, if it was used
         }else
           //..nothing found
     }catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
         //..problem processing file...
                    }
```

Comment: What did you notice when you stepped through your code using a debugger? Why are you creating a new `StringBuilder` each time you find a match? Just append the match to the `StringBuilder`. Does this code compile, `+fndPwrdsCNTR+" PASSWORD(S) FOUND!"` should be a syntax error.

Comment: Hi Jonny, yes, +fndPwrdsCNTR+" PASSWORD(S) FOUND!" compiles. I see the silly mistake, going to try again. Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

You can't create new StringBuilder on each line. Instead create it before reading lines. The code:

```
givenAccnt = searchTextField.getText();//else, user is using search field to get given account
try
   {
builder=new StringBuilder();//initialize builder to store matched lines
      scanner = new Scanner(file);        //initialize scanner on file
      while(scanner.hasNextLine())        //while lines are being scanned
      {   
         getLine = scanner.nextLine();          //gets a line
         int i = getLine.indexOf(' ');          //get first string-aka-accnToken
         accntToken = getLine.substring(0, i);    
       }
       if(givenAccnt.equals(accntToken))   //if match   
       {
          collectedLines = builder.append(getLine).toString();
          psswrdLabels = new JLabel(collectedLines, JLabel.LEFT);
          psswrdLabels.setAlignmentX(0);
          psswrdLabels.setAlignmentY(0);
          fndPwrdsCNTR += 1;     //counter for number of passwords found 
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, psswrdLabels ,+fndPwrdsCNTR+" PASSWORD(S) FOUND!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);    //shows window with matched passwords (as JLabels)
                            searchTextField.setText("");    //clears search field, if it was used
         }else
           //..nothing found
     }catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
         //..problem processing file...
                    }
```